# Hahn-Banach from "Every vector space has basis"

Tags: functional-analysis

What is the simplest way to prove Hahn-Banach starting from the AC-equivalent that every vector space admits a basis?

Comment: Which Hahn-Banach? I suppose the extension dominated by a sublinear functional?

Comment: Yes, that's the one I mean.